# Copy image from one worksheet (always named "Template") to worksheet with variable names

Tags: excel, vba, image

I need to copy an image from my invoice template worksheet to another worksheet with variable names. For example, the name of the sheet could be "03-000008" or "04-000005" or any other name. This problem would be easy to solve if the sheets had the same name, but since they are variable, I am struggling. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

[image]

Tim suggested that I add the code I am working with (thanks Tim!) Here is the code that almost works, but instead of pasting the image to my new, active invoice sheet, it pastes it right on the template itself.

```vb
Sub image()

With ActiveSheet
Set i = Sheets("Template")
Set e = ActiveSheet

    i.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 4")).Select
    Selection.Copy
    e.Range("b1:b4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You could try to use the "Like" operator. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator

Comment: `Like "##-######"` would match the pattern you show.  Your question states "the name of the sheet could be "03-000008" or "04-000005" or any other name"  Pretty sure you don't mean literally "any other name", so it would be helpful to expand on that a little (what is *not* a matching name?)  Your best approach here would be to loop over the worksheets in your workbook (plenty of examples here) until you find one with a name which meets your criteria.  As always here, questions with some code fare better than those without.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. You are correct; I don't literally mean "any other name." It will follow the pattern of XX-XXXXXX, using only integers. Here is one of the codes I've tried thus far:

Sub copyimage()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Range("A1:A4").Copy
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B4").Select
ThisWorbook.ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub

The image below shows another code, and I think it would work if I could replace the sheet name with "activesheet," or a variable that is set to activesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Sub image()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Shapes("Picture 4").Copy
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name Like "##-######" Then    'check matches pattern [2digits-6digits]
            ws.Paste Destination:=ws.Range("B1")
            MsgBox "Pasted to " & ws.Name
            Exit For                        'no need to check further
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

If all you need to do is copy the image from Template to the activesheet then:

```vb
Sub CopyLogo()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Shapes("Picture 4").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("B1")
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, You're a Genius! This works, almost. It pastes the image to the same worksheet (03-300010) for as many sheets as I have (ie, 03-300020, 03-300030, 03-300040... totally 8 worksheets). So there are 8 images on 03-300010 rather than one image on each sheet. I'm not sure how we can make Excel select the next worksheet that is like ##-######. Thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: Did you just want to copy the image from "Template" to whatever the active sheet is?  FYI the loop I posted should exit after the first match, so I'm not sure why it would paste to all matching sheets unless you removed the `Exit For`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need to do.

Comment: Oh my wow - that totally worked! It seems so simple! Thank you a million, this was very helpful and so important! God bless you!